# Address already in use in targetcli iser enable

Tags: iscsi, rdma

kindly help me to fix this problem
I am using *"targetcli-2.0rc1"*
I have created the portal with IP address 192.168.1.11 and port no : 3260
When I am doing ***"iser_enable"*** then it throws following error

/iscsi/iqn.20...168.1.11:3260> iser_enable 
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/configshell/shell.py", line 983, in run_interactive
    self._cli_loop()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/configshell/shell.py", line 806, in _cli_loop
    self.run_cmdline(cmdline)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/configshell/shell.py", line 927, in run_cmdline
    self._execute_command(path, command, pparams, kparams)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/configshell/shell.py", line 902, in _execute_command
    result = target.execute_command(command, pparams, kparams)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/targetcli/ui_node.py", line 216, in execute_command
    return UINode.execute_command(self, command, pparams, kparams)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/targetcli/ui_node.py", line 101, in execute_command
    pparams, kparams)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/configshell/node.py", line 1405, in execute_command
    result = method(*pparams, **kparams)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/targetcli/ui_target.py", line 1042, in ui_command_iser_enable
    self.portal._set_iser_attr(True)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rtslib/target.py", line 870, in _set_iser_attr
    fwrite(path, "1")

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rtslib/utils.py", line 106, in fwrite
    file_fd.close()

IOError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

when i am using Soft-RoCE, iser_enable has no issues...
when I am trying with Soft-iWarp i got the above issue

my ibv_devices o/p is as follows

root@VCHN145:~# ibv_devices

```
device                 node GUID
------              ----------------
siw_wlan0           c038969609070000
siw_eth0            3417eb90714e0000
siw_lo              7369775f6c6f0000
```

root@VCHN145:~#

kindly help me to fix this problem

Comment: for testing I have created another portal with port number 3261

Comment: and following is the output of the netstat

Comment: tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:3260       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:3261       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4003            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4040/skype      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1407/sshd

Comment: It looks like somebody else is listening on port 3260, hence the "IOError: [Errno 98] Address already in use". I'd actually try to answer your question if I knew anything about iWarp or RoCE.